# Leaflet Search Control not showing on map

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to add the leaflet search functionality on my map but the control is not showing. My map is exported from QGIS using the qgis2leaflet plugin. I have tried the following code:

```
var searchControl = new.L.Control.Search({layer: searchLayer});
searchControl.addTo(map);
```

I have also tried:

```
map.addControl (new L.Control.Search({});
```

Comment: Are you getting any Errors in the console?

Comment: We really need to see a jsfiddle or demo site here to begin to troubleshoot this.

Comment: I am not getting any errors. Unfortunately the demo site is on my local server. Here is the jsfiddle of the javascript part - http://jsfiddle.net/Jonahke/m6skkpya/

Comment: @snkashis Here is the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Jonahke/m6skkpya/

Comment: There are a lot of errors in the code you provided on that jsfiddle from what I can tell, also I'm not too familiar with the plugins you are using. Did you include the necessary JS *and* CSS file? See my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/m6skkpya/3/

Comment: @chrki Thanks for the code. It helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code solved my problem. Thanks to @chrki

```
var searchLayer = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
map.addControl( new L.Control.Search({layer: searchLayer}) );
```